# Placement of the spaceports on our Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, earth, rocket-science

Why are spaceports located at certain points (site/place) on our Earth?

Is there a physical reason I don't really know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Space stations are usually put into low Earth orbit, high enough that they are well clear of the outer atmosphere and are not affected by atmospheric drag. This makes them easy to reach, but high enough to do all kinds of scientific research. They also need to have an orbit where they are clear of the Van Allen radiation belts and clear of hazardous space debris. From this orbit they would make good launching points for future expeditions to Mars and other planets. A rocket starting from an orbiting space station would need much less power to reach Mars than one starting from the ground. If your question is about launching sites on Earth, they are usually located as close to the equator as possible, so the French Arianne launching site is located in French Guyana, and the main NASA launching site is at Cape Kennedy in Florida. Both sites look out over the sea, which means there is less chance of hitting populated areas if things go wrong. These near-equatorial launching sites mean that the rockets get maximum assistance from the rotation of the Earth when they take off, so can carry heavier payloads.